# Are questions about how I can help in the COVID19 crisis on topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

There's been a bit in the news about persons 3d printing parts to help in the COVID19 pandemic, but as mentioned in [this Forbes article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/sarahgoehrke/2020/03/29/fda-oversight-emerges-for-additive-manufacturing-resources-in-pandemic-response/),

> Community response is high, but also in short supply is often the knowledge of exactly what will help, and how and where to deploy that help. 3-D printing random designs found online might feel helpful, but if those designs don’t meet usage criteria or aren’t produced in satisfactory environments, ultimately it’s often just a waste of plastic.

So are questions related to which parts I should print to be most helpful be on topic? Or questions about where I can find guidance on the best support?

Comment: -1, only because I think that we aren't equipped to answer COVID requirement questions. A medical SE site might be better (if one exists). I'd plus one the "ultimately it’s often just a waste of plastic" quote though. People printing random ventilator parts at home in non-clean environments, using random plastics, doesn't help in the slightest (unless it is for prototyping).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that specific question how and where you can help printing parts for the COVID-19 pandemic are of value for the future. But, problems with printing, settings, orientation, etc. are on-topic.